# Pasar datos de php a ajax

Tags: php, laravel, ajax

Espero me puedan ayudar con un problema que no se como resolver. Tengo unos datos Ip que rescato de una base de datos y por cada ip que tenga asociada una dirección las voy listando en una tabla, y luego tomo esa ip y realizo un `ping`, esto me resulta sin problemas, pero solo con la primera que encuentra, no se como hacer que ejecute mi código `ajax` por cada ip del listado. Estos son mis códigos.

Pagina desde donde llamo la función `ajax`:

```
@extends('layouts.app2')
@section('contenido')
@php
              set_time_limit(0); 
              //$users = App\User::all(); 
              foreach ($enlaces as $nombre)
              {
                  $ssee=$nombre->Sse_nombre;
                  $tipo=$nombre->Sse_Tpi_id;
                  if($tipo == '1')
                  {
                    $titulo='SSEE';
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    $titulo='Central';
                  }
              }
@endphp
      <div class='container'>
        
        <h1>Detalle Enlaces {{ $titulo}} {{$ssee}}</h1> 
        <form id='formulario'>
        <div class='row md-2'>
                   <button class='btn-secondary btn-default row mt-5' type='submit' id='analizar' name='analizar'>Analizar</button>
      
          </div>
          <div class='row'>
              
                <table class='table  table-format table-hover'>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope='col'>#Id</th>
                      <th scope='col'>IP</th>
                      <th scope='col'>Equipo</th>
                      <th scope='col'>Marca</th>
                      <th scope='col'>Modelo</th>
                      <th scope='col'>Tipo Enlace</th>
                      <th scope='col'>Prioridad</th>
                      <th scope='col'>ISP</th>
                      <th scope='col'>Cod.Servicio</th>
                      <th scope='col'>N° Contacto</th>
                      <th scope='col'>Correo Contacto</th>
                      <th scope='col'>ESTADO</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                 @foreach ($enlaces as $enla)

                  
                     <tr>
                      <td>{{ $enla->Enl_id}}</td>
                      <td>{{ $enla->Enl_num_ip}}</td>
                      <td>{{ $enla->Tpq_nombre}}</td>
                      <td>{{ $enla->Mar_nombre}}</td>
                      <td>{{ $enla->Mod_nombre}}</td>
                      <td>{{ $enla->Tpe_nombre}}</td>
                      <td>{{ $enla->Pri_nombre}}</td>
                      <td>{{ $enla->isp_nombre}}</td>
                      <td>{{ $enla->Enl_codigo_serv}}</td>
                      <td>{{ $enla->isp_telefono}}</td>
                      <td>{{ $enla->isp_correo}}</td>

                      <td><div id='estado'><div id='respuesta'></div></td>
                      <input id='prueba1' type='hidden' name='ip' value='{{ $enla->Enl_num_ip}}'>
                          </tr>
                   
                @endforeach

                  </form>
                  <script src="{{ asset('js/app/ping.js')}}"></script>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
         </div>
     </div>          
@endsection
```

Este es mi código `js`:

```
 var formulario =document.getElementById('formulario');
var respuesta =document.getElementById('respuesta');

formulario.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
console.log('pinchaste el boton')
var datos = new FormData(formulario);
console.log(datos.get('ip'))


fetch('http://localhost/scadabita2/resources/views/app/post.php',{
  method:'POST',
  body:datos
})
.then( res => res.json())
.then( data => {
  console.log(data)
  if(data === 'error')
  {
    respuesta.innerHTML=`<div>
   error
    </di>`
  }else{
    respuesta.innerHTML=`<div>
    ${data}
    </di>`
  }
  
})
})
```

Y este es mi código `php` donde realizo los `ping`:

```
 <?php 
$data=$_POST['ip'];
 $PING1='ping '.$data.' -n 4';
   $res=shell_exec($PING1);
   $var=strstr($res, '(100% perdidos)');
   $findme='recibidos = 0';
   $pos = strpos($res, $findme);

   if($pos == false) 
   {
       $findme='recibidos = 4';
        $pos = strpos($res, $findme);

            if($pos == false)
            {
                $RESULTADO="OKNOK.jpg";
                echo json_encode("<img src='../img/".$RESULTADO."'>");
            }
            else 
            {
                $RESULTADO="Ok.jpg";
                echo json_encode("<img src='../img/".$RESULTADO."'>");
            }
            
    }else
        {
        $RESULTADO="NOk.jpg";  
            echo json_encode("<img src='../img/".$RESULTADO."'>");        
        }

?>
```

Comment: Todos tus inputs tienen el mismo nombre `name="ip"`, al procesar el formulario se envía solamente uno. Cambia el nombre a `name="ip[]"` y en PHP manéjalo como arreglo.

Comment: @Triby hola tribi, perdón la molestia, pero me podrías mostrar como hacerlo, he intentado hacerlo como me decías pero no se como enviar el name="ip[]" como arreglo y como capturarlo en javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes corregir algunas cosas como:

- Eliminar el *div* `id="estado"`, no le veo utilidad... o cerrarlo y cambiar ID por clase
- Evitar repetir IDs, tanto para *div* como para input

  - Cambia ID del *div* por clase
  - Elimina ID del *input* y agrega corchetes al nombre
- Coloca el *input* dentro de la misma celda de *respuesta* para tener un HTML válido

```
            <td>
                <div class='respuesta'></div>
                <input type='hidden' name='ip[]' value='{{ $enla->Enl_num_ip }}'>
            </td>
```

En javascript los cambios son mayores, porque vas a mostrar los resultados de cada IP en *respuesta* y es necesario enviar una petición por IP, de lo contrario, los resultados llegarán hasta que se procesen todas.

Hay que recorrer todos los campos y ejecutar la petición AJAX en una función aparte, evitando el uso de funciones anónimas dentro del ciclo.

```
// Asegurar que se cargó el DOM antes de comenzar
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // Asignar directamente el evento submit al formulario, no necesitas tenerlo en variable
    document.querySelector('#formulario').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        // Evitar comportamiento por defecto del formulario
        e.preventDefault();
        // Obtener los campos por nombre, el circunflejo ^ es para indicar que "inicia con"
        let ips = document.querySelectorAll('[name^="ip"]');
        // Recorrer todas las IP y ejecutar la petición AJAX
        ips.forEach(ip => procesarIps(ip));
    });
});

function procesarIps(ip) {
    // Crear formData y agregar IP actual
    let datos = new FormData();
    datos.append('ip', ip.value);
    
    // Seleccionar DIV de respuesta, llegando por TD padre
    let respuesta = ip.closest('td').querySelector('.respuesta');
    
    // Ejecutar petición AJAX
    fetch('http://localhost/scadabita2/resources/views/app/post.php',{
        method:'POST',
        body:datos
    })
    .then(res => {
         // Ver la respuesta del servidor
         console.log(res);
         // Fue una respuesta adecuada?
         if(res.ok) {
             return res.json();
         }
         // Lanzar mensaje de error
         throw 'Error en respuesta AJAX';
    })
    .then(data => {
        // Debes recibir un JSON con propiedad img... o algo falló
        if(data.img) {
            respuesta.innerHTML = data.img;
        } else {
            respuesta.innerHTML = '(Error en respuesta)';
        }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        // ¿Falló la petición?
        console.log(error.message);
        respuesta.innerHTML = '(Error en petición)';
    });
}
```

En PHP solo hay que hacer unas modificaciones para devolver un JSON válido:

```
<?php 
$data=$_POST['ip'];
$PING1='ping '.$data.' -n 4';
$res=shell_exec($PING1);
$var=strstr($res, '(100% perdidos)');
$findme='recibidos = 0';
$pos = strpos($res, $findme);

if($pos == false) {
    $findme='recibidos = 4';
    $pos = strpos($res, $findme);
    if($pos == false) {
        $RESULTADO="OKNOK.jpg";
    } else {
        $RESULTADO="Ok.jpg";
    }
} else {
    $RESULTADO="NOk.jpg";  
}
// Enviar un JSON con elemento img y la imagen correspondiente
echo json_encode(['img' => "<img src=\"../img/$RESULTADO\">"]);
```

Se puede enviar solo el nombre de la imagen y crear el elemento adecuado en javascript, llévatelo de tarea.

**Muy importante:** No copies y pegues este código porque no ha sido probado, trata de entenderlo primero, ver qué hace cada cosa e irlo aplicando en tu proyecto por partes, revisando y depurando.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda, estoy viendo el código y hay muchas cosas que no sabia y he tratado de ir entendiendo, lo ejecute paso a paso como decías,para ir viendo que hacia, pero me da un error en el fetch si lo veo por consola me muestra "failed to fetch" y no se que puede ser.

Comment: Acabo de modificar la respuesta para tratar de ver si el servidor devuelve algo y la respuesta es adecuada o no.

Comment: Triby esto es lo que muestra el servidor al ajecutar el codigo:


NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. 2 ping.js:45:15





.catch(function(error) {
      // Fallo la peticion
      console.log(error.message);
      respuesta.innerHTML = '(Error en peticion)';
  });

y nuevamente gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: @proteus8, actualicé la respuesta, había olvidado `.preventDefault()` en el evento _submit_

Comment: funciono perfecto!!! de verdad muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda y buena voluntad.

Comment: No hay problema, para eso estamos. No olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada.